Import module ts: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "html2canvas". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"
This is my first time doing a webapplication and therefore my first time using typescript / javascript / node modules. I'm using Webstorm and vanilla html, css and typescript.
Everything went fine so far but now i'm trying to import the "html2canvas" library. I installed it with npm install html2canvas. The installation seemed to have worked and my typescript file finds the library and its functions.
But after compiling the files and opening the html, i always get this error message: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "html2canvas". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../". (fileManager.js:1:25)
Since i'm not completely sure how npm works in the first place, i'm sure this is a silly mistake and someone can help me! :)
I will now provide you with some details:
This is the first line of the typescript and also of the compiled javascript file: import html2canvas from "html2canvas"
This is my project hierarchy:
Project Hierarchy
This is my package.json:
{
  "name": "parsonify",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "html2canvas": "^1.4.1"
  }
}

This is my tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ES2020",
    "target": "ES2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "frontend/build"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "frontend/src/scripts/**/*"
  ]
}

I already tried reinstalling the library and compiling my ts-files by console.

Can you share the full error with its stacktrace?

The short answer is that npm is a package manager for running Node scripts - scripts that run in Node.js on the command line, not in a browser.
The simplest way to load scripts into an HTML page is to load them from a CDN, which gives you a web link you can include, if this approach is supported by the package.
If you want to use npm modules in a web page for anything beyond a trivial situation you will want to use tools that handle converting them for the web.
Full explanation and ways to do this are provided in this question: How to set up a VS Code project that includes referenced JavaScript npm modules
I guess this question should be considered as a duplicate, but I really don't know the system here on SO :)

I solved this problem by using Webpack for compiling my application. It seems like the browser needs tools like this to handle modules.
